# Why does increased conjugation in a molecule cause the wavelength absorbed to decrease (i.e. why does a red-shift occur)?

Tags: photochemistry

I was recently looking at a paper about [novel organic dyes for efficient dye-sensitized solar cells](https://doi.org/10.1039/B603706B) and one point the authors made was that out of the two dyes mentioned the one with a larger pi-conjugated system had a red-shift compared to the other one.

I understand that a larger pi-conjugated system would increase the stability of the molecule and decrease the gap between the HOMO and LUMO energies, but how would this cause a red-shift?

Comment: They were talking about actual color, not wavelength. Larger conjugation gives order like yellow -> orange -> red

Comment: In ancient time, when wavelength increases due to any event, it's called a red-shift (wavelength shifting towards red color). Similarly, when wavelength decreases due to any event, it's called a blue-shift (wavelength shifting towards blue color). To date, some of researchers still use this terminology.

Comment: Blue/red shift term is used regularly, but rather in physics, e.g. context of the Doppler effect or General relativity. It is not usually used in chemistry, if it is like a  comparison between two different objects.

Comment: In ancient times sound a bit to much long time ago. Red or blue shift must be read as "shift to the red" (or to the blue). In general, unless is a single line shifting, there is marginal or no correspondence to the actual colour, it is even somehow complementary. Obviously as red has wl longer than blue, red shift means bathocromic shift and blue means hypsochtomic.shift.

Comment: I do assume that now you can make the link to absorption as it is clear to you that generally more extended the effective conjugation is, lower is the energy gap. Your nickname is quite red-shifted :))